# Kafka client unit testing for dotnet

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

Im looking for assistance in writing unit tests for kafka in dotnet. Confluent seems to provide a Mocks for producers and consumers in Java only.

Comment: Did you find solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Confluent uses Docker Compose to start actual brokers (at least for integration tests)

You may also look through the unit tests folder for their own code

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/tree/master/test

They tried to use Moq mocking library against IProducer, but that code is commented - https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/test/Confluent.Kafka.UnitTests/MoqExample.cs